# Question regarding the generation of all combinations n-pairs of parentheses

Tags: algorithms, combinations

A book Im reading asks me to create an algorithm to print all valid (i.e., properly opened and closed) combinations of n-pairs of parentheses.

It then goes ahead to give this as an example for n=3 

[ '((()))', '(()())', '(())()', '()(())', '()()()' ]

 As I understand in a combination it doesnt matter the order so would it really be correct to consider items at index 2 and 3 to be different combinations?

Comment: [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics)

Comment: It doesn't mean "combination" in that sense. They are distinct, as far as *parenthesizations* are concerned.